# Trying to convert mix string into the array but unable to get exact output

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, explode

**Hi I am trying to convert mix string into the array but unable to get exact output.**

I have already used explode function to remove pipe sign but i am not able to get exact output

**Below is my code what i have tried so far** :

```
$customstring = "Eye Width=3/4 in|Finish=Nickel|Hook Opening=7/16 in|Locking Type=Spring Loaded Plunger|Material=Zinc Die Cast|Mounting=Swivel Eye|Overall Length [Nom]=3 1/2 in|Type=Swiveled Securing Hook|Wt.=0.09 lb";

echo "String :<br>".$customstring;
$testarray = explode("|",$customstring);

echo "ARRAY<br><pre>";
print_r($testarray);
```

**AS an output i am getting below :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Eye Width=3/4 in
    [1] => Finish=Nickel
    [2] => Hook Opening=7/16 in
    [3] => Locking Type=Spring Loaded Plunger
    [4] => Material=Zinc Die Cast
    [5] => Mounting=Swivel Eye
    [6] => Overall Length [Nom]=3 1/2 in
    [7] => Type=Swiveled Securing Hook
    [8] => Wt.=0.09 lb
)
```

**But  i want to remove this " = " equal to and make left value as key and right as value. see my expected output below.**

**But my Expected output is this :**

```
Array
(
    [Eye Width] => 3/4 in
    [Finish] => Nickel
    [Hook Opening] => 7/16 in
    [Locking Type] => Spring Loaded Plunger
    [Material] => Zinc Die Cast
    [Mounting] => Swivel Eye
    [Overall Length [Nom]] => 3 1/2 in
    [Type] => Swiveled Securing Hook
    [Wt.] => 0.09 lb
)
```

Advanced Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches shown consecutively:

**1)** Use additional `explode` function combined with `list` function:

```
$customstring = "Eye Width=3/4 in|Finish=Nickel|Hook Opening=7/16 in|Locking Type=Spring Loaded Plunger|Material=Zinc Die Cast|Mounting=Swivel Eye|Overall Length [Nom]=3 1/2 in|Type=Swiveled Securing Hook|Wt.=0.09 lb";

$pairs = explode("|", $customstring);
$result = [];
foreach ($pairs as $p) {
    list($k, $v) = explode('=', $p);
    $result[$k] = $v;
}

print_r($result);
```

---

**2)** Another alternative solution would be using `preg_match_all` and `array_combine` functions:

```
$customstring = "Eye Width=3/4 in|Finish=Nickel|Hook Opening=7/16 in|Locking Type=Spring Loaded Plunger|Material=Zinc Die Cast|Mounting=Swivel Eye|Overall Length [Nom]=3 1/2 in|Type=Swiveled Securing Hook|Wt.=0.09 lb";
preg_match_all("/([^=|]+)=([^+|]+)/", $customstring, $m);
$result = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);

print_r($result);
```

The output(same for both approaches):

```
Array
(
    [Eye Width] => 3/4 in
    [Finish] => Nickel
    [Hook Opening] => 7/16 in
    [Locking Type] => Spring Loaded Plunger
    [Material] => Zinc Die Cast
    [Mounting] => Swivel Eye
    [Overall Length [Nom]] => 3 1/2 in
    [Type] => Swiveled Securing Hook
    [Wt.] => 0.09 lb
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd loop through your new array and explode each item on the `=` character.

```
foreach($testarray as $item){
    $arr = explode("=", $item);
    $testarray[$arr[0]] = $arr[1];
}
```

Only issue is you'd then need to tidy up `$testarray` to remove the numeric keyed items.

To fix this I'd just create a final array instead

```
foreach($testarray as $item){
    $arr = explode("=", $item);
    $final[$arr[0]] = $arr[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$string = "Eye Width=3/4 in|Finish=Nickel|Hook Opening=7/16 in|Locking Type=Spring Loaded Plunger|Material=Zinc Die Cast|Mounting=Swivel Eye|Overall Length [Nom]=3 1/2 in|Type=Swiveled Securing Hook|Wt.=0.09 lb";

$formed_data = explode("|", $string);
$desired_data = [];
foreach ($formed_data as $single_string) {
    $words= explode("=", $single_string);
    $desired_data[$words[0]] = $words[1];
}
var_dump($desired_data);
/**
 * Output
 */
array(9) {
  ["Eye Width"]=>
  string(6) "3/4 in"
  ["Finish"]=>
  string(6) "Nickel"
  ["Hook Opening"]=>
  string(7) "7/16 in"
  ["Locking Type"]=>
  string(21) "Spring Loaded Plunger"
  ["Material"]=>
  string(13) "Zinc Die Cast"
  ["Mounting"]=>
  string(10) "Swivel Eye"
  ["Overall Length [Nom]"]=>
  string(8) "3 1/2 in"
  ["Type"]=>
  string(22) "Swiveled Securing Hook"
  ["Wt."]=>
  string(7) "0.09 lb"
}
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

By using foreach you can get desired result

Answer (score 1):

> @Manthan Dave simply do with foreach with make a condition like below:

```
<?php
    $customstring = "Eye Width=3/4 in|Finish=Nickel|Hook Opening=7/16 in|Locking Type=Spring Loaded Plunger|Material=Zinc Die Cast|Mounting=Swivel Eye|Overall Length [Nom]=3 1/2 in|Type=Swiveled Securing Hook|Wt.=0.09 lb";
    echo "String :<br>".$customstring;
    $testarray = explode("|",$customstring);

    echo "ARRAY<br><pre>";
    print_r($testarray); // before
    foreach($testarray as $key => $val){
        if(strpos($val, "=") || strpos($val, "=") == "0"){
            $temp = explode("=", $val);
            $testarray[$key] = $temp[1];
        }
    }
    echo "ARRAY<br><pre>";
    print_r($testarray); // after
```